# Fabric added styles are missing

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I was trying to add integrate `Fabric-Twiiter` login in my app. While during the wizard Fabric added couple of things in my project.
Since then I am getting this error:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light'.
```

In a file `v32\values.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/Users/android/workspace/jenkins/workspace/fabric-android-staging-release/sdk/kits/digits/src/main/res/values-v21/themes.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Digits_default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="dgts__accentColor">?android:attr/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have no idea from where it came and what to do about it, please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a material design theme, and is found in API 21 of Android.  You'll need to make sure you have that API level installed in the SDK tools, and then, in your build.gradle file, change your compileSdkVersion:

```
android {
  ...
  compileSdkVersion 21
  ...
}
```

You may also have to tweak the targetSdkVersion, but I don't think I had to do that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works to resolve above mentioned problem about missing v21 styles.

Comment: My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 24 and it is not working